# vb.net selenium select element from dropdown

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I don't know much about selenium. I'm trying to select an element from a dropdown to click on it, but vb.net doesn't find this element. or it finds another element that has the same class name.
It is the following dropdown menu on aliexpress.

[image]

And this is the code I have written so far....

```
    Dim chromeDService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService() 'hides command prompt
    chromeDService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
    Dim opt As New ChromeOptions()
    opt.AddArguments("headless") 'prevents driver from opening a new window
    Dim driver As IWebDriver = New ChromeDriver(chromeDService, opt)
    driver.Navigate.GoToUrl(URL_AS_STRING) 'the URL as String
    driver.Manage.Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)

    If driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("switcher-info")).FindElement(By.ClassName("currency")).Text = "USD" Then
        Console.WriteLine("changing currency...")
        'driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("EUR")).Click()
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("switcher-info")).Click()
        driver.Manage.Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        Dim element As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("switcher-common")).FindElement(By.ClassName("switcher-currency-c")).FindElement(By.ClassName("select-item"))
        Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("innerText"))
    End If
```

My question now is, how can I select and click on the element with the currency?
I intend to click on it so that it selects another currency.

Of course I could also make everything less complicated and include an exchange API. But the real rates do not match with the prices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply by clicking the corresponding elements one by one exactly what the real user does via the GUI.
I see Selenium in VBA doesn't have explicit waits, so only the implicitly wait can be used as you already defined it `driver.Manage.Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)` and since it was defined we do not need to define it anymore until we want to define it for some other value.
This is what I wrote.
I hope this should work:

```
If driver.findElementByXPath("//a[@id='switcher-info']//span[@class='currency']").Text = "USD" Then
    Console.WriteLine("changing currency...")
    driver.findElementByXPath("//span[@class='currency']").Click()
    driver.findElementByCssSelector(".switcher-currency .select-item").Click()
    driver.findElementByXPath("//a[@data-currency='EUR']").Click()
    driver.findElementByXPath("//button[@data-role="save"]").Click()
```

In case there are pop-ups appearing on the aliexpress home screen disturbing the above code run try do the following:

```
If driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[contains(text(),'Don')]").Count Then
   driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[contains(text(),'Don')]").Click() 
If driver.FindElementsByXPath("//img[@class='btn-close']").Count Then
   driver.FindElementsByXPath("//img[@class='btn-close']").Click() 
If driver.FindElementsByXPath("//img[@class='close-btn']").Count Then
   driver.FindElementsByXPath("//img[@class='close-btn']").Click()
```

And only after that run the code above so that the whole code will be something like this:

```
If driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[contains(text(),'Don')]").Count Then
   driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[contains(text(),'Don')]").Click() 
If driver.FindElementsByXPath("//img[@class='btn-close']").Count Then
   driver.FindElementsByXPath("//img[@class='btn-close']").Click() 
If driver.FindElementsByXPath("//img[@class='close-btn']").Count Then
   driver.FindElementsByXPath("//img[@class='close-btn']").Click() 

If driver.findElementByXPath("//a[@id='switcher-info']//span[@class='currency']").Text = "USD" Then
    Console.WriteLine("changing currency...")
    driver.findElementByXPath("//span[@class='currency']").Click()
    driver.findElementByCssSelector(".switcher-currency .select-item").Click()
    driver.findElementByXPath("//a[@data-currency='EUR']").Click()
    driver.findElementByXPath("//button[@data-role="save"]").Click()
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code with xpath. unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried debugging it and it shows an element not found exception at ("//a[@data-currency='EUR']"). By the way none of them, except ("//a[@id='switcher-info']") and maybe the save button, is clickable?

Comment: Normally I use Selenium with Java, but for other languages like Python and C# there is an ExpectedConditions too . VBA is missing this, and it's a problem... Can you put some hardcoded sleeps between all the clicks to let the dialogs open properly?

Comment: I tried that too, it responds with an "Element Not Interactable Exception". on ("//span[@class='select-item']"). When I remove .click() it responds with "Element Not found Exception" on ("//a[@data-currency='EUR']"). Have you tried it with Java? Does it work there?

Comment: ("//span[@class='select-item']") still shows "element not interactable exception". Thank you so much for your effort!

Comment: Did the drop list open by clicking on `driver.findElementByXPath("//span[@class='currency']").Click()` ?

Comment: Thank you :D if you need any information, I can send them to your dm or something. I'm not familiar with stackoverflow. 
Yes, it opened.

Comment: it's strange the drop-list sometimes opens and sometimes not.. I tried changing findelementbyxpath to findelementbyclassname etc. but no matter which method I use. I still have to click it by myself sometimes. If I click it everything else works properly. Thank you!

Comment: maybe this is because of the pop-up appearing when the page is loaded first time?

Comment: I guess so, @itronic1990 mentioned it. I tried 
 `Dim options As New ChromeOptions()
  options.AddArguments("headless")
  options.AddExcludedArgument("disable-popup-blocking")` it didn't work either

Comment: I have tried to add some code to close the pop-ups. Can't debug it on my side, sorry...

Comment: it's all good you helped me out alot! thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

You need to close all the popups before interacting with any element on the page. Try this:-

```
driver.findElementByXPath(".//div[contains(text(),'notifications')]//following::img").Click()
driver.findElementByXPath(".//img[@class='btn-close']").Click()

driver.findElementByXPath(".//a[@id='switcher-info']").Click()
driver.findElementByXPath(".//div[@data-role='switch-currency']").Click()
driver.findElementByXPath(".//li/a[@data-currency='EUR']").Click()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but it's not working unfortunately. (No Such Element Exception) at (".//div[contains(text(),'notifications')]//following::img")

Comment: Can you try without headless mode on to see what is happening on the page when page is complete?

Comment: I did and the problem was that it didn't click on "switcher-info". I had to hard-code a second click() for the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the ClassName-Selector ist not the right one.
It is not a real dropdown like `<select>` but a dropdown-menue of links.

the Link for US-Dollar looks like this:

```
 <span class="select-item chang-border" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.home.1000001.i0.650c2145pgspp2">
         <a rel="nofollow" href="javascript:;" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.home.1000001.40">USD ( US Dollar )</a>
</span>
```

You can use the FindElementByCssSelector to access this link:

```
driver.FindElementByCssSelector("[data-spm-anchor-id=a2g0o.home.1000001.40]").Click()
```

For EURO it is:

```
 driver.FindElementByCssSelector("[data-spm-anchor-id=a2g0o.home.1000001.43]").Click()
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still shows an exception and says invalidselectorexception.